# Ways to play background audio with a PWA

Tags: javascript, browser, progressive-web-apps

I have quite a simple usecase, I need to have a wesbite & PWA that's able to send audio queues to the user.

These would be pooled from a server with as a continuous audio stream (that usually returns nothing) or as individual mp3s that can be sent over with push notification, or any other mechanism really.

The issue I'm struggling with here is how to play audio from a PWA or website while it's not active (i.e. user isn't focusing on the tab / PWA is in the background)

My current approach was with an always active `<audio>` element where the source points to a streaming endpoint that returns nothing until there's something to transmit... but this seems buggy at best, the connection randomly drops, the audio element doesn't play the last 1 or 2 seconds of the audio... etc

Is there a standard way to do this that wouldn't require using a native app ?